# React-boostrap popover dismissal on content hover

Tags: react-bootstrap

I have `OverlayTrigger` with `trigger='hover'`. Expected behaviour here would be hiding popover when I moved cursor out of it. However, library hides popover when I move cursor out of button, i.e.

```
<OverlayTrigger trigger='hover' placement='left' overlay={
  <Popover>
    ... content ...
  </Popover>
  }>
  <Button bsStyle='default'>name</Button>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

So, when cursor out of button on popover content (if I want to click on link there for instance) it disappears.

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

I am just starting to learn React. My solution to this is to set **trigger** option as **"manual"**, and add **onMouseOver={fn}** and **onMouseOut={fn}** to manually show and hide the PopOver content. Here is my sample code:

```js
var popOver_timer;
var Pop = React.createClass({
  mixins: [TimerMixin],
  mouseOverhandler: function() {
    this.clearTimeout(popOver_timer);
    this.refs.pop.show();
  },
  mouseOuthandler: function() {
    popOver_timer = this.setTimeout(
      ()=> {this.refs.pop.hide();},
      50
    );
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div onMouseOver={this.mouseOverhandler} onMouseOut={this.mouseOuthandler}>     
        <OverlayTrigger ref="pop" placement="bottom" trigger="manual" container={document.body} overlay={
          <Popover onMouseOver={this.mouseOverhandler} onMouseOut={this.mouseOuthandler}>
            <a href="/">This Page</a>
          </Popover>}>
          <a href={this.props.popUsrUrl}>
            <button>PopOver</button>
          </a>
        </OverlayTrigger>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Besides react-boostrap, I also require react-time-mixin and use the react-setTimeout. It is because when your mouse moves from the button to the popover content, the onMouseOut will be triggered first, then the onMouseOver. Therefore, a time delay for onMouseOut should be set. I set it to 50 ms. Hope it helps.